# How to sketch the level curves of $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, 3d

I've been practising functions of several variables for college and I've been working with circles all the time $(x^2 + y^2)$, however, I still can't figure out how to solve non circular shapes, as far as I know by research $(x^2 - y^2) $ represent two queues that pass through the origin, and when you plot the function on 3D using the Google's plot you get this:

[Google search for function's plot](https://www.google.com/#q=x%5E2+-+y%5E2)

The thing I don't understand is why does it look like a wave?, how do you determinate the Z/Height values for each queue and why X queue starts from below 0 and gains Z while Y starts from 0 and loses Z?

I would like that someone demonstrate to me (also including level curves) how to solve this exercise, sorry if it's an obvious question but I can't figure it out, really, plus, teachers don't help.. Thank you.

Comment: the wave thing is $z=x^2 - y^2.$ You should get some graph paper and carefully draw, say, $x^2 - y^2 = 1,$ then $x^2 - y^2 = 4,$ then $x^2 - y^2 = -1,$ then $x^2 - y^2 = -4.$ There is nothing we can say that will do as much good as you carefully graphing those four sets in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Ex: $x^2 - y^2 = 4$, then $x^2 = 4 + y^2$, then $x = sqrt(4 + y^2)$, that would be for X, then I do for Y and both are roots so that determinates the 'wave' behaviour, is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean that if you get some actual graph paper and draw, by hand, some reasonably simple graphs, you will learn something. One of them is indeed two arcs, $x = \sqrt {4 + y^2}$ and  $x = - \sqrt {4 + y^2}.$

Comment: Now that I think of it, also draw $x^2 - y^2 = 0.$

Comment: Actually it is the hyperbolic paraboloid, which is a `saddle`  surface. For each $z_0\ne 0$, the level curve $x^2-y^2=z$ is a hyperbola whose asymptotes are the lines $x-y=0, z=z_0$ and $x+y=0,z=z_0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you freeze $y$ (hence work in the vertical plane $y=Y$), you get curves $$z=x^2-Y^2$$ which are upward parabolas with their vertices at $(0,Y,-Y^2)$. The latter curve is obviously a downward parabola with its vertex at the origin.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in order to determine the shape of the graph, you need to understand that the          [(x^2/a) -(y^2)/b = z/c] will result in a saddle shape or a hyperbolic paraboloid. Basically, the crest, or bottom, of the level curve will be at (0,0,0) and there will a parabolic curve on the z-x plane with a decline on the 3D space:

[image]

Comment: You sample figure is upside down.